# digital servo won't seek to angle if delta between current position and target is more than ~15 degrees

Tags: mobile-robot, robotic-arm, rcservo

My students and I are using a Hiwonder LD-220MG digital servo to position a "shoulder" on a robot. [image: robot bulldozer on workbench]

We are seeing a behavior (on every one of these servos that we test) that it won't go between arbitrary angle values. If the angle we want to go to is too far from where the servo is currently positioned, then it either ignores the new target value, or very slowly creeps to it if it's not "too far". If the target angle is "close", say within 15 degrees, the servo will correctly and quickly move to the target angle.

So far, we've looked at voltage (right at the top of the spec for the servo), signal quality (nice solid 50Hz square wave coming from a PCA9685 16-Channel 12-Bit PWM Servo Driver), and software (used a hobby R/C tester).

Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Comment: contact Hiwonder ... there may be some type of error detection behavior in play ... try issuing the same destination command several times

Comment: Could this be a deg-rad conversion problem? 15degrees is suspiciously close to pi/2 *10... it is worth doublechecking...i always run into problems like that so I am always supicious when i see 1,5, 3, 15, 30... degrees

Comment: The servo is a digital one, are you sure you're submitting commands intermittently (i.e. allowing it to get to a good rest after each command)?

Comment: Are you asking it to move there too quickly?  If you slow down the rpm will it seek the angle correctly?

Comment: I am running into the same problem. Could you explain what kind of workaround you have found to get it to work? We are using similar servo's from HiWonder. The path we are on now is to ramp from the previous angle to the new setpoint, but we found out that we have to give the servo time to get there.
Any input would be highly appreciated. Thanks, Maarten.

Answer (score 0):

Gever, do you have any clue on what type of feedback control you are using? This is usually a PID kind of controller (at least as far as I know). It could be that the once you give a large target position, the controller values get too high, causing an error to your servo. Adjusting the values of the PID (or any kind of) controller parameters would maybe help.

Comment: Jelle, thanks for giving it a good think. Since the hobby servos are self-contained, we don't get to tweak the PID... we've got a clunky software work-around going now that we are going to just go with for the pilot launch of our Mars program: http://tinkeringschool.com/mars

Comment: Allright good to know. Good luck!